# Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, boot

I have a dual boot system on same hard disk. Some of my friends say that dual booting a laptop can lead to its deterioration because some part of both OS keep running at once. It sounds weird but I can access my windows part of hard-disk from Ubuntu. Is it so? Should I remove either OS?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore what your friends say... the only "deterioration" that would be noticed is the normal wear and tear of your hard disk... if you do a traditional "dual boot" then only **one** operating system can be "in use" at any one time - i.e. you can't boot Windows and Ubuntu simultaneously.

You *can*, however, access the Windows (NTFS) partition through Ubuntu. Ubuntu should have automatically identified that you have Windows installed and installed alongside it... this is they key... Ubuntu knows about (and can mount/read/write) the NTFS partition. See this AskUbuntu solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/568577/pulling-files-from-a-windows-ntfs-partition-into-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

These are absolutely absurd kind of things people say about dual boot systems. There is really no need to worry about any kind of deterioration. I have been maintaining dual boot on both my desktop and laptop for the past 5-6 years now and I never faced any kind of problem due to it, both OSs run just fine. So no need to worry, you can keep both the OSs if you need them.

Now to answer your second question. Yes you can access Windows (NTFS) partitions from Ubuntu. Its normal and it doesn't mean Windows is running along side Ubuntu. The only OS that will be running is the one you have booted into.